# Counting combinations in c or in python

Tags: python, c

Hello I looked a bit on this topic here but I found nothing that could help me.

I need a program in Python or in C that will give me all possible combinations of a and b that will meet the requirement n=2*a+b, for n from 0 to 10. a, b and n are integers.
For example if n=0 both a and b must be 0. For n=1 a must be zero and b must be 1, for n=2 a can be 1 and b=0, or a=0 and b=2, etc.

I'm not that good with programming. I made this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int a,b,n;
    for(n = 0; n <= 10; n++){
        for(a = 0; a <= 10; a++){
            for(b = 0; b <= 10; b++)
                if(n == 2*a + b)
                    printf("(%d, %d), ", (a,b));
        }
        printf("\n");       
    }
}
```

But it keeps getting strange results like this:

```
(0, -1079628000), 
(1, -1079628000), 
(2, -1079628000), (0, -1079628000), 
(3, -1079628000), (1, -1079628000), 
(4, -1079628000), (2, -1079628000), (0, -1079628000), 
(5, -1079628000), (3, -1079628000), (1, -1079628000), 
(6, -1079628000), (4, -1079628000), (2, -1079628000), (0, -1079628000), 
(7, -1079628000), (5, -1079628000), (3, -1079628000), (1, -1079628000), 
(8, -1079628000), (6, -1079628000), (4, -1079628000), (2, -1079628000), (0, -1079628000), 
(9, -1079628000), (7, -1079628000), (5, -1079628000), (3, -1079628000), (1, -1079628000), 
(10, -1079628000), (8, -1079628000), (6, -1079628000), (4, -1079628000), (2, -1079628000), (0, -1079628000),
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/y9vM8)

Any idea what is wrong?

Also if I could do this for Python it would be even cooler. :D

Comment: Is this [homework](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/homework-on-stackoverflow)? If so, it's fine to ask for help but not solutions, and homework should be noted as such. Also, "strange results" isn't very descriptive. State exactly what you expect to happen and what actually happens. If *a* and *b* are integers, there will be an infinite number of solutions. Do you mean they are whole numbers (i.e. non-negative integers)?

Comment: I formatted the code for you, showed an example of "strange results", and added more appropriate tags. In future please do this yourself if you want good answers.

Comment: When you say "a, b and n are integers" did you mean "non-negative integers"? Otherwise I believe there are infinite answers. Also, is there a requirement that a ≥ b? Otherwise you can just give the same pair of numbers a and b but swap the order.

Comment: Isn't this just a simple [diophantine equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> for n in xrange(11):
    print ", ".join(str((a, n-2*a)) for a in xrange(n/2+1))
...     
...     
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(0, 2), (1, 0)
(0, 3), (1, 1)
(0, 4), (1, 2), (2, 0)
(0, 5), (1, 3), (2, 1)
(0, 6), (1, 4), (2, 2), (3, 0)
(0, 7), (1, 5), (2, 3), (3, 1)
(0, 8), (1, 6), (2, 4), (3, 2), (4, 0)
(0, 9), (1, 7), (2, 5), (3, 3), (4, 1)
(0, 10), (1, 8), (2, 6), (3, 4), (4, 2), (5, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

The C version isn't working because you've used the comma operator. The comma operator evaluates all operands and the result is the last evaluation, for example:

```
int i = 4;
int j = 3;

int k = (i += 4, i + j);

// k is now 11 because i += 4 was done first (making i = 8)
// and then i + j is evaluated to 11 and is assigned to k.
```

In your `printf` call, you're asking to print two decimal integers but you're only providing one. This is because `(a, b)` evaluates `a` (essentially a no-op), and then evaluates and “returns” `b` (also a no-op). Since you're only providing one argument, `printf` prints garbage for the second value because there's no real data being given.

Simply remove the parentheses so that `a` and `b` are actual arguments to the `printf` call, not operands of the comma operator.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your C version remove the parentheses around `(a,b)`:

```
printf("(%d, %d), ", a, b);
```

For a Python solution this should give you a good start:

```
for n in range(0, 10 + 1):
    for a in range(0, 10 + 1):
        for b in range(0, 10 + 1):
            if n == 2 * a + b:
                print a, b
    print
```

Comment: I saw that mistake, but what is the compiler doing with (a,b)?

Comment: The binary sequence (comma) operator evaluates both of its operands in left to right order, and takes the value of the right hand operand.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way in python is:

```
for n in range(0, 10 + 1):
    for a in range(0, 10 + 1):
        b = n-2*a
        if b >= 0:
            print a, b
    print
```

The point is that you don't have to iterate over possible b's, there's maximum one good b for given n and a.

Edit:
You're right.
No need to check that b is an int.

Comment: Why do you need to check if it's an int? `int - int * int` is always an int.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the most pythonic way of doing this:

```
generator = ((a, n-2*a) for n in range(10+1) for a in range(10+1))
for pair in generator:
    print pair
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the answers :D I realized that in C I had extra () but I wanted to see how that would look in python. Thanks again.